# Android Studio MediaPlayer not working properly

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I am creating a mobile application, something like a service for listening to music, and I ran into the following problem.
When I start another track, the previous one continues to play.
I don't know how to solve it, the `mediaPlayer.isPlaying` shows true or false, depending on the situation.

**The Code:**

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_player);
    back = findViewById(R.id.backTrack);
    pause = findViewById(R.id.pauseTrack);
    next = findViewById(R.id.nextTrack);
    track_id = getIntent().getStringExtra("track_id");
    Log.d("333", "onCreate: before playing " + mediaPlayer.isPlaying());
    validMusic();

    pause.setOnClickListener(e -> {
        count++;
        if (count % 2 == 1) {
            pauseMusic();
            pause.setImageResource(R.drawable.play);
        } else {
            startMusic(track_id);
            pause.setImageResource(R.drawable.pause);
        }
    });      
}
public void pauseMusic() {
    mediaPlayer.pause();
}

public void startMusic(String id) {
    try {
        mediaPlayer.setDataSource("myURL" + id);
        mediaPlayer.prepare();
        mediaPlayer.start();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
}

public void stopMusic() {
    if (mediaPlayer != null) {
        mediaPlayer.stop();
        mediaPlayer.release();
    }
}

public void validMusic() {
    if (mediaPlayer != null && mediaPlayer.isPlaying()) {
        stopMusic();
    } else {
        startMusic(track_id);
     }
    }
   }
```